# Read more on each link

Tags: jquery

Trying to display a div which is closet to the "Read more".

```
$('.btn-read-more').click(function(){
    $('.readMoreMeta').slideToggle();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/fva4hzgw/2/

Comment: you can use `$(this).closest('.readMoreMeta')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.readMoreMeta').slideToggle();` this will apply for all `readMoreMeta` tags. You need to select specific one. So you can access it with finding previous div with `.prev('div)` & then `.find('.readMoreMeta')` inside that div.

Try as below:

```
$('.btn-read-more').click(function() {
    $(this).prev('div').find('.readMoreMeta').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code here:**

when you click the readmore button then the **'prev'** a element and his children **'readMoreMeta'** slide toggle.

you can also learn jquery selectors for improve your skill here the link: [jquery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

```js
$('.btn-read-more').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('.text-content').children('.readMoreMeta').slideToggle(300);
  });
```

```css
.readMoreMeta {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-content clearfix">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <p class="readMoreMeta">As a result, dealership Sales Consultants deepened their connections with customers through dialogue about a luxury lifestyle that goes beyond cars. This communication is critical to enrich the guest experience while strengthening one-to-one relationships.</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-read-more">Read More</a>

<br><br>

<div class="text-content clearfix">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  <p class="readMoreMeta">As a result, dealership Sales Consultants deepened their connections with customers through dialogue about a luxury lifestyle that goes beyond cars. This communication is critical to enrich the guest experience while strengthening one-to-one relationships.</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-read-more">Read More</a>

**Thank you**
```